# Git Remove Large file from git repository

Tags: git, version-control

I have a repository which has a file more than 100MB. I am using BFG [an alternative to git-filter-branch](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)
it cleaned my file successfully. But when I want to push it to remote repository its giving an error `remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/branch-name (you should pull first)`

the steps I have followed is listed below

```
$ git clone --mirror git://example.com/some-big-repo.git
java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M myrepo.git
$ cd myrepo.git
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

After this `git push` which displays the below errors

```
Counting objects: 3070, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (961/961), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3070/3070), 47.79 MiB | 307.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3070 (delta 1644), reused 2834 (delta 1565)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/baranchName (you should pull first)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/baranchName (you should pull first)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/develop (you should pull first)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/baranchName (you should pull first)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/baranchName (you should pull first)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/baranchName (you should pull first)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/baranchName (you should pull first)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/tagversion1.2 (you should pull first)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/tagversion1.3 (you should pull first)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/tagversion2 (you should pull first)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/v1.2-fixes (you should pull first)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/version1 (you should pull first)
To ssh://repo-path
 ! [remote rejected] baranchName1 -> baranchName1 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [remote rejected] baranchName2 -> baranchName2 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [remote rejected] baranchName3 -> baranchName3 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [remote rejected] baranchName4 -> baranchName4 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [remote rejected] baranchName5 -> baranchName5 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [remote rejected] baranchName6 -> baranchName6 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [remote rejected] baranchName1 -> baranchName7 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [remote rejected] tagversion1.2 -> tagversion1.2 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [remote rejected] tagversion1.3 -> tagversion1.3 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [remote rejected] tagversion2 -> tagversion2 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [remote rejected] v1.2-fixes -> v1.2-fixes (non-fast-forward)
 ! [remote rejected] version1 -> version1 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to
```

Comment: do you push to Bitbucket or GitHub as GitHub will warn you when pushing files larger than 50 MB. You will not be allowed to push files larger than 100 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in branch master, you will need to do a force push.

```
git push -f origin master
```

The reason for this is that you've changed your history, and you can't just fast-forward the remote repository to include these major changes.

Comment: But when i try to do push with the above command it gives me error `git push origin master
error: --mirror can't be combined with refspecs
` Since my repository is is `myrepo.git (BARE:master)`